# Ideas for Implementing multiple views for the same data

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, structure

I am using CodeIgniter, but the question applies to any MVC framework. I have a custom CMS which allows for the management of 5 different websites. Users log in and switch between these sites. They can add content to each of the areas of the sites. The CMS and data that can be entered is the same for each site.

The public facing sites all look completely different and represent different brands even though they contain the same data as all the others.

So how would you go about implementing these views? Are there any design patterns I should be looking at?

The only way I can think of doing this right now is to put a switch statement inside of each controller > action to grab a different view for each website but there must be a much more clever way of doing this. I want to get get around producing loads of code that looks like this:

```
class Home extends Controller {

    public function getPage()
    {
        $website = $this->session->userdata( "site_id" );
        switch( $website )
        {
            case "1":
                // load view one
            break;
            case "2":
                // load view 2
            break;
            // etc etc
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Write a `CoreController` class that extends `Controller` and have all the other controllers extend the `CoreController` class, in your case `Home`:

  ```
  class CoreController extends Controller {}
  class Home extends CoreController {}
  ```
- Create folders in your view folder with site_ids:

  ```
  application/views/1/
  application/views/2/
  ```
- Switch the base folder in the constructor of `CoreController`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the way Django does with its [optional "sites" framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/):

1. Add Site to your models.
2. Establish a relationship between Site and your existing models.
3. Load Site::get_current_site() and use its attributes.

Residuum's approach is good for organizing the files.